# PowerShell - Is there a way to Log into the local locked computer via PowerShell script called by Task Scheduler?

Tags: powershell, authentication, windows-10

I created a PowerShell script to run locally on my desktop computer. It opens a program (Start-Process), takes a screenshot, and emails that screenshot via an smtp server. This script is called hourly from task scheduler.

Everything works perfectly if I am logged into my computer, but my problem is that if my computer is locked, the screenshot is of the lock screen. Is there a way to log into my local PC via PowerShell so that the screenshot is of the program that is running?

Notes about my setup: My desktop is running windows 10, I am logged in 24/7, but I lock the screen when I leave so that nobody else in the shared office can use my computer

Comment: If your Scheduled Task is running with elevated Admin privs, you might be able to use tscon to unlock the screen:  $sessionid=((quser $env:USERNAME | select -Skip 1) -split ‘\s+’)[2]; tscon $sessionid /dest:console   , take the screenshot, and then re-lock the screen:   C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation.  In my present environment, I can't test it tho.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately this gives an access denied message when I try it. I think tscon cannot be used locally like this. I will run a few more tests though.

Comment: This is not really a PowerShell issue or code problem, which what we are here for, so really an off-topic thing as no code is required for what you are after. However, use a remote session to change the registry settings to allow for autologin, or if you have creds on the box and RDP is enabled, RDP to the box and edit the registry. Create a task, set it to run whether a user is logged on or not. Force a reboot.

Comment: I am running this script from my local desktop PC. I edited my question to clarify that it is all local, and not Windows server. Apologies if my question was not clear

Comment: @the In PowerShell 5.1 window running w/ admin priv. Does not work. first had to use runas `runas /savecred /user:$env:computername\$env:username "tscon $sessionid /dest:console"` just to get tscon to connect and the screenshot is all black when locked. works when not locked.  On the upside I found a nice little command line screencapture at https://superuser.com/a/943947/1003800